# How to iterate over a range and then append items from list to it?

Tags: python, discord.py

Right now the for loop that adds reactions at the end of the message takes `number_of_responses`, which is what I want. But I would also like the `e.add_field` fields be added based on `number_of_responses` (along with the right emoji in the `name` field and then add items from the list `answers` to their `value`s).

```
async def run_script(params):
    params = params
    channel = client.get_channel(<obfuscated>)
    emoji_numbers = ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣", "4️⃣", "5️⃣", "6️⃣", "7️⃣", "8️⃣", "9️⃣"]
    question = params[0] # string
    answers = ast.literal_eval(params[1]) # list
    number_of_responses = len(answers) # int
    e = discord.Embed(title='Title', description='Desc.', color=discord.Color.blue())
    e.add_field(name=question, value='\u200b', inline=False)
    e.add_field(name='1️⃣', value='Mobiel', inline=False)
    e.add_field(name='2️⃣', value='Tablet', inline=False)
    e.add_field(name='3️⃣', value='Laptop', inline=False)
    e.add_field(name='4️⃣', value='Desktop', inline=False)
    e.add_field(name='5️⃣', value='TV', inline=False)
    message = await channel.send(embed=e)
    for i in range(number_of_responses):
        await message.add_reaction(emoji_numbers[i])
    for i in range(4, -1, -1):
        time.sleep(1)
    await channel.send("Going to sleep now")
    await client.close()
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. How can you add the `e.add_field` lines to the loop if their `value`s are hard-coded?

Comment: You never use the `answers` list except checking its size. What are its values?

Comment: Right now. the `e.add_field` lines are hardcoded, but I'd like for it to be a loop, based on the length of `answers` (which is variable, depending on the commandline input.


```example: `./emojivvdd.py "Testquestion" "['List', 'of', 'Answers']"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop over indices. Just [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the `answers` and the `emoji_numbers`:

```py
for emoji, answer in zip(emoji_numbers, answers):
    e.add_field(name=emoji, value=answer, inline=False)
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Comment: Thank you /SO/ much. I did not know about `zip` but this is exactly what I needed!